# CGAL Polyhedron demo (5.0.2) boost problem

Tags: boost, cmake, cgal

I seem to be unable to configure the Polyhedron demo on Cgal 5.0.2.

I am able to make and build everything else so wondered what the problem was? I am faced with this output upon using cmake.

```
Boost version: 1.65.1
Found the following Boost libraries:
  serialization
  iostreams
  regex
    CMake Error at Installation/cmake/modules/CGAL_Boost_iostreams_support.cmake:36 (set_target_properties):
      set_target_properties called with incorrect number of arguments.
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      Polyhedron/demo/Polyhedron/Plugins/Classification/CMakeLists.txt:9 (include)
```

I am not well-versed on cmake etc. so apopolgies if there is something I have missed. I have trawled the internet on this to no avail on this so far. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: The CMakeLists.txt doesn't match the CMake version. Either upgrade CMake, or fix the compatibility issue in the build script. It might be enough to add a https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/cmake_minimum_required.html

Comment: Thank you  - this was indeed the issue. An upgrade from CMAKE 3.10 > 3.17 solved the problem and  I was then able to make and build the demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to sehe for the suggestion. An upgrade from CMAKE 3.10 > 3.17 solved the problem and I was then able to make and build the demo.